# Angular8: Run oninit or onchanges for components referenced in response text

Tags: angular, ngoninit, ngonchanges

I have MathJacks loaded and working when the text is put into a template. But I am retrieving a large body of text from the server. This text is in HTML as it is heavily parsed and setup on the server.

(FYI I'm using the sanitizer on the returned content, bypassSecurityTrustHtml. I have tried without sanitizing and get the same result.)

Using the inspector I can confirm the code is there in the DOM:
`<mathjax [content]="$a = {\frac{v-u}{t}} $" class="box"></mathjax>`

I have fed the equation text via both variable and static text in the template as a text and it works on initial load.

The only thing I can figure is that the  component isn't being interpreted as its not native to the template and is injected after the server call resolves.

How can I run the initialisation or onchanged function for the  components once they have been injected?

Thank you

Comment: You can not render HTML as a string that contains Angular expressions or components.

Comment: This is not really possible this way. You basically want to resolve an angular component run-time right?

Comment: yeah not possible, angular compiles into JS when it runs so it can not interpret any angular code at run-time. You might want to compile that piece in the server and send back the result but to me this sounds more like there is a flaw with the basic design